# Can I check if the userid and password are valid in Keyclock?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

The user sends me its id and password.
Then I want to check if it is valid on the keycloak.
I can try to log in, but the session is created in keycloak.

I even thought about to log out after logging in.
But this is very inefficient.

Is there a way to check if id and passwd are valid without creating a session?
If there was such a way, my task will be very easy.

If there is no way, I have to log in instead of my user and manage the token instead.
This is relatively more complex to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781449317843/ch04.html). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

As far as I know, out-of-the-box, there is no way to avoid creating the session.

> If there is no way, I have to log in instead of my user and manage the
> token instead. This is relatively more complex to implement.

Not necessarily. Since the password and username are handed over to your application, you can use the following approach:

- Create in Keycloak a client (in the appropriate realm) with direct grand access flow enabled (known as [Resource Owner Password Flow](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781449317843/ch04.html) in OAuth2);
- Set the access token for that client to be very-short lived (*e.g.,* one minute).

Make a `POST` request with the username and password to the client, like this:

```
curl --request POST \
        --url "http://$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/realms/$REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
        --data client_id=$CLIENT_ID \
        --data username=$USERNAME \
        --data password=$PASSWORD \
        --data grant_type=password
```

If you get back as a response a token, then it means that the user credentials are valid; if not, then those credentials are invalid.

In case you get back the token, you can explicitly logout of the session, for instance, as follows:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo $TOKEN | jq -r .access_token)
SESSION_STATE=$(echo $TOKEN | jq -r .session_state)

curl -k -X DELETE "http://$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/realms/master/sessions/$SESSION_STATE" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Or since the access token is very short-lived, let Keycloak eventually clean up the session.

Comment: client_secret is also needed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181444/keycloak-grant-type-password-in-custom-identity-provider

Comment: @AnshumanChatterjee only if the client is confidential, for public clients it is not necessary